# Using Enterprise Architect API for documentation in Gitbook

Tags: enterprise-architect

we use Sparx Enterprise Architect for creating our UML diagrams. Also we write our architecture documentation based on Gitbook. Currently we copy & paste the diagrams into MS Paint and save them as PNG to use it the image in the Gitbook.

Our build system then creates a HTML version of the Gitbook and publishes the documentation to our webserver.

The question is that we want to reference the diagrams directly from Gitbook/Markdown to Enterprise Architect. Is there any kind of REST API for Enterprise Architect available to directly link to a PNG/image?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but you'll need to install the [cloud server component](https://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise-architect/cloud-services/cloud-services.html).

As an alternative you could also:

- [Export the model as HTML](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_publishing/htmlreports.html) and reference the element/diagram on there. You can use the GUID to get stable hyperlinks
- Use the regular [automation API](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/theautomationinterface.html) to build your own export/synchronize mechanism.